# Python Selenium - Handling an element that will not click

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium

I am having issues with a pop up window that will not close. I have tried using try/except to catch any errors but somehow the element is located and close button is clicked but the element does not actually disappear from the page. Below is code I have tried but i believe there is a more efficient way to handle it.

```
def isElementPresent():
    try:
        close_button = find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='x-close']")
        if close_button == "Some_Element":
            close_button.click()
    except:
        print('No Such Element')
        return False
    return True

elementSwitch = isElementPresent()

while elementSwitch == True:
    run = isElementPresent()
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: print the stacktrace and check which exception is occurring??

Comment: Try to click on Elements using JavaScriptExecuter. Try -((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", close_button);

Comment: @GaurangShah No errors come up

Comment: @ Ankur I have tried using JavascriptExecutor but still the button is sometimes not clicked

Comment: Sometimes the object actually handling the click or closure could be nearby object. So instead of clicking on the object you are trying, try nearby objects or parent objects